# Database Design For Image Table

Tags: sql-server, database, database-design

I am trying to workout if the follow can be done better in terms of DB design. Any advice on why it's wrong/right would be appreciated.

I have 3 Tables

```
Person
Car
Image
```

Both Cars and Persons can have images all references to the images are stored in the image table.

```
Person has > Images
Car has > Images
```

The image table ends up looking like this..

```
Image
ID   NAME    CAR_ID   PERSON_ ID
1    img1    10       NULL
2    img2    NUll     8
```

It now seems I have lots of NULLs in my table, but I need to know if the image is for the a Car or a Person.

So how could this be done better, if at all?

Comment: Yes both car and person can have many images. Would it be best if I added a category table? I could sort by cat car or car person? would this work better?

Comment: A category table would also make your system more extensible, I would imagine. Any chance you'll be linking more tables to Image ? Ie - in addition to Person and Car, you'll be linking - say: MotorCycle. But, maybe you would want to consider chris's answer below - to avoid having a category table altogether.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would end up with fewer nulls if you store the references to the images in the Car and Person tables if there's a one to one relationship.   If you have multiple images, you would do best to have a table that just stores relationships.

This table would look like this:

```
DATATYPE    DATAID    IMAGEID
 1           10         1
 2            8         2
```

In the first column, 1 refers to car and 2 refers to image.

Comment: So this would be like a category table?

Comment: Yes.  The DataType column could contain the index of an item in a category table. The table mentioned above would be a relationship table that captures the relationship between the category, car, person, and image tables.

Answer (score 0):

You dont *need* those two fields in the image table. You can query the person and car tables to see if an entry exists which matches the image id.

But, you may find their existence is convenient and performant.

Comment: @carlpett, heh interesting :). But I ain't one to care if words are official.

Comment: ;) Just find it interesting how often the word pops up, even though it doesn't "really exist".